Is it possible to override a Point2D object from a superclass to a Point2D.Float?
I have defined a class called Entity with a Point2D object in it called pos. The class is a superclass and it's not specified if pos should be a Point2D.Float or a Point2D.Double, that's left for the inheritors to decide. The problem is I don't know how to override this object to make it a Point2D.Float (for example) without getting an error.
import java.awt.geom.Point2D;

public class Entity {
    Point2D pos;

    public Entity(Point2D pos) {
        this.pos = pos;
        //...
    }
    //...
}


import java.awt.geom.Point2D;

public class Enemy extends Entity {
    // Somehow overrite "pos" so it must be Point2D.Float within this subclass
    public Enemy(Point2D.Float pos) {
        this.pos = pos;
        //...
    }
    //...
}

I tried to simply insert the @Override annotation before declaring Point2D.Float pos;, but the virtual environment I was working on indicated that that was an illegal use of @Override.
I wasn't sure what I was supposed to do and I didn't find any answers on Stack Overflow.
Thank you in advance.
Edit: Made Enemy extend Entity, sorry for the confusion.

Does Enemy extend Entity?  Do you have control over the Entity class?

A Point2D could be either Float or Double, just pass it whatever you want.  Are you sure you need to restrict this class to accepting only Float?

that is, public Enemy(Point2D.Float pos) { super(pos); } I am assuming public class Enemy extends Entity (despite not posted as such)

You can make it generic with Point2D bound
public class Entity<P extends Point2D> {
    P pos;

    public Entity(P pos) {
        this.pos = pos;
        //...
    }
    //...
}

... and then narrow down to Point2D.Float for a subclass
public class Enemy extends Entity<Point2D.Float> {
    public Enemy(Point2D.Float pos) {
        super(pos);
    }
}


What happens here?

Superclass now declares a type parameter, it is now a generic class. This is normally used when the class can work with subjects of different types but it still makes difference which is used for specific instance. For example, List can work both with String and Integer, but list of strings is not the same thing as list of integers. So does Entity - it can work with Point2D.Float or Point2D.Double but it should be clear which one is chosen.
There is an upper bound in superclass' type parameter declaration P extends Point2D. It means that superclass doesn't work with any type, but  only with subtypes of Point2D. It also means that raw type Entity or wildcard type Entity<?> behaves similar to initial non-generic version of Entity. This ensures your code that already uses Entity class may be left unchanged (there will be warnings though).
Subclasses of such a generic class must follow bounds declared in superclass and may choose to re-declare type parameter(s), possibly with narrowed bound...

    public class Enemy<P extends Point2D.Float> extends Entity<P>


...or pick explicit type.

    public class Enemy extends Entity<Point2D.Float>


Sorry, I don't understand what you just did, but it seems like it may be the answer I'm looking for. Could you please explain your code?

Thank you very much, your answer was very helpful.

The @Override annotation is intended mainly for methods. Note that a constructor is a special method and cannot be given the @Override annotation.
Since classes Point2D.Double and Point2D.Float are subclasses of Point2D, then according to the Liskov substitution principle an instance of Point2D.Double is considered to also be an instance of Point2D. Similarly for an instance of Point2D.Float.
Hence the constructor for class Enemy can take a parameter of type Point2D.Float and simply call the superclass constructor with its parameter.
import java.awt.geom.Point2D;

public class Enemy extends Entity {

    public Enemy(Point2D.Float pos) {
        super(pos);
    }
}

This means that a call to Enemy constructor must be passed an instance of Point2D.Float.
Edit
Regarding your comment, you can use pattern matching.
import java.awt.geom.Point2D;

public class Entity {
    Point2D pos;

    public Entity(Point2D pos) {
        this.pos = pos;
    }

    public void showPosX() {
        switch (pos) {
            case Point2D.Double d:
                System.out.printf("%f (double)%n", d.x);
                break;
            case Point2D.Float f:
                System.out.printf("%f (float)%n", f.x);
                break;
            default:
                System.out.printf("%f (unknown)%n", pos.getX());
        }
    }
}


import java.awt.geom.Point2D;

public class Enemy extends Entity {

    public Enemy(Point2D.Float pos) {
        super(pos);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Point2D.Float p = new Point2D.Float(3.14f, 2.72f);
        Enemy e = new Enemy(p);
        if (e.pos instanceof Point2D.Float f) {
            System.out.printf("%.2f (float)%n", f.x);
        }
        e.showPosX();
    }
}

Running above code produces following output:
3.14 (float)
3.140000 (float)


Ok, but now assume I'm trying to access the x component in pos of an instance of Enemy directly for some reason, so enemy.pos.x instead of enemy.pos.getX(). My virtual environment now gives me an error saying Cannot resolve symbol 'x' because it doesn't know that pos will always be a Point2D.Float.
The error I get when running the code is: (build failed)
C:\Users\********\IdeaProjects\Game\src\Game.java:40:27 java: cannot find symbol   symbol:   variable x   location: variable pos of type java.awt.geom.Point2D
How can I solve this?

@GabrielVinagreCoppens answer is edited.
